# Return the number of times a character shows up in a string

Tags: java, string

```
public class StringFind {

   /** findLetter looks for a letter in a String
    * @param String letter to look for
    * @param String text to look in
    * @return boolean true if letter is in text
    * After running the code, change this method to return
    * an int count of how many times letter is in the text.
    */
    public int findLetter(String letter, String text) {
        int count = 0;
        for(int i=0; i < text.length(); i++) {
            if (text.substring(i, i+1).equalsIgnoreCase(letter)) {         
                count = count++;
            }
        }
         
        return(count);
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        StringFind test = new StringFind();
        String message = "Apples and Oranges";
        String letter = "p";
        System.out.println("Does " + message +  " contain a " + letter + "?");
    }
}
```

There is an error with this code and I am not sure how to fix it. This code is supposed to return the number of times a letter shows up in a message that the user inputs. I have struggled to figure out what I need to change without error.

Comment: Hi @BenBerinsky - your code doesn't call the `findLetter` method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first mistake is in `findLetter` where you have

```
count = count++; // this is effectively count = count;
```

That should be

```
count++; // or count = count + 1;
```

Then you aren't calling `findLetter`. Change your current `println` to something like

```
System.out.printf("%s contains %s %d times.%n", message, letter, 
        test.findLetter(letter, message));
```

With no other changes, I then get

```
Apples and Oranges contains p 2 times.
```

Answer (score 0):

To complete the answer given by Elliott Frisch, your function has the first parameter wrong it is an char instead of a string and given that, you need to change the way you are finding the char in the string by using the function charAt to make it more simple (https://www.w3schools.com/java/ref_string_charat.asp). It’s not a mandatory change, but I think it makes more sense.

```
public class StringFind {
    /** findLetter looks for a letter in a String
     * @param String letter to look for
     * @param String text to look in
     * @return boolean true if letter is in text
     * After running the code, change this method to return
     * an int count of how many times letter is in the text.
     */
    public int findLetter(char letter, String text)
    {
        int count = 0;
        for(int i=0; i < text.length(); i++)
        {    if(text.charAt(i) == letter)
            count++;
        }


        return(count);

    }

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        StringFind test = new StringFind();
        String message = "Apples and Oranges";
        Character letter = 'p';
        System.out.printf("%s contains %s %d times.%n", message, letter, test.findLetter(letter, message));
    }
}
```